# Not getting active consumers list in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

I have installed ActiveMQ version 5.16.5, but when I try to check active consumers list by clicking on queue name I am not getting any consumers. However, in dashboard it shows queue has 16 consumers.

displays number of active consumers - 16:
[image]
displays no active consumers for same queue:
[image]
Is there any configuration I am missing into activemq.xml or any other file? I'm expecting to display all consumers from the numbers shown in pic1.

Comment: 5.12.1 was released in Oct of 2015 and is extremely out of date so first thing is to upgrade to a current release.

Comment: I installed 5.16.5 but same problem

Comment: Share the code snippet showing the consumers queue names. Are they wildcard or composite consumers?

Comment: @MattPavlovich queue names having "." and "-" in names to separate words. no other special char.

Answer (score 2):

My ActiveMQ version is 5.16.6

[image]

I have resolved it . I find the root cause. In org.apache.activemq.web.BrokerFacadeSupport

```
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Collection<SubscriptionViewMBean> getQueueConsumers(String queueName) throws Exception {
        String brokerName = getBrokerName();
        queueName = StringUtils.replace(queueName, "\"", "_");
        ObjectName query = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=\"" + brokerName
                + "\",destinationType=Queue,destinationName=\"" + queueName + "\",endpoint=Consumer,*");
        Set<ObjectName> queryResult = queryNames(query, null);
        return getManagedObjects(queryResult.toArray(new ObjectName[queryResult.size()]), SubscriptionViewMBean.class);
    }
```

[image]
these quotes are redundant,when i delete these quotes,and replace this class file to activemq-web-5.16.6.jar and restart active mq . the the consumer list appears.
[image]

Comment: I made a JIRA (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-9298) and will make a patch. Thanks!